# How can I add multiple functions into one?

Tags: c++

I understand how to pass variables from functions but I've been stuck on adding multiple functions together? I want to add all of the double values stored in the functions into one function called "totalBillAmount". (navyCreditBill + wfStudentBill +....etc). Also, is there any way to combine the functions even tho they all have different double values? (i.e. combining all the Bills to make ONE function called Bills)

```
//this is my main file
Budget budget;

budget.introText();
double inputNavyCreditCardBill = budget.navyCreditBill();
double inputWellsStudentLoanBill = budget.wfStudentBill();
double inputSprintPhoneBill = budget.sprintBill();
double carBill = budget.carBill();
double capitalOneCreditCard = budget.capitalCredit();
double fedStudentLoan = budget.fedCreditBill();
double navyPersonalLoan = budget.navyPersonalLoan();
double totalMoneyOnHand = budget.totalMoneyOnHand();
double totalBillAmount = 

    double moneyRemaining = totalMoneyOnHand - totalBillAmount;
    std::cout << std::endl << "Money Remaining: $" << moneyRemaining << std::endl;

    double extraMoneyTowardsDebt = moneyRemaining * .7;
    std::cout << std::endl << "Extra Money For Debt: $" << extraMoneyTowardsDebt << std::endl;

    double moneyFromCreditForGirlFriend = moneyRemaining * .3;
    std::cout << "Extra Money From Credit For Girlfriend!: $" << moneyFromCreditForGirlFriend << std::endl;

    double extraMoneyForMe = moneyRemaining * .3;
    std::cout << "MA MONEY BITCH: $" << extraMoneyForMe << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Kindly follow the rules of [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question with the more information about your problem. And, what do you mean by **adding functions**?

Comment: I updated my code. Sorry I am new to this website. I want to take for example "totalMoneyOnHand" and add each function(I have one fuction for one double value of a bill(i.e. carBill, sprintBill) so I want to create another function called totalMoneyOnHand by adding the values stored in all the other functions.

Comment: Thanks for all the downvotes guys :) Please keep them coming..its not as if I'm new to programming and this website or anything like that!

Comment: @Azeem I mean "totalBillAmount" not "totalMoneyOnHand"

Comment: You can call all those function inside your `total` function and return the total from there like this: http://ideone.com/oRoa04. Is this what you mean by `combining`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have the following functions:

```
void func1(int bar1) { ... }
void func2(int bar2) { ... }
void func3(int bar3) { ... }
```

If you want to combine all of these functions inside a new bigger one all you need to do is pass the arguments that each small function requires through the arguments list of the big one:

```
void bigFunc(int bar1, int bar2, int bar3) {
  ...
  func1(bar1);
  func2(bar2);
  func3(bar3);
}
```

Now in your case you also have return values which makes things a little bit more complicated. Depending on what you want to do with these you can either do the calculation inside the big function and then return a single result or use an array, structure or a more elaborate container to store the separate results.

Since in your case you just want to return a single result it's quite easy. Below you can see an example with a bunch of functions (`double sum(double, double, double)`, `double pow(double, double)` and `double sub(double, double)`). You should be able to adapt this to your scenario:

```
// Use the arguments list of bigFunc to pass down the arguments that each of the smaller function requires
void bigFunc(double arg1, double arg2, double arg3) {

  // Use temporary variables to store the return value of each smaller function
  double s = sum(arg1, arg2, arg3);
  double p = pow(arg1, arg3);
  double sb = sub(arg1, arg2);

  // Do whatever you want we the results and return it
  return s + p - sb;
}
```

Comment: LOL It was not that much the question you asked but the way you posted it that is content-wise the explanation what you wanted was not clear enough (you even got a comment with a solution where the person who posted it added "Is this what you mean by `combining`?).